# Pino swap mergingObject and message params

Tags: pino

I'm using fastify and pino-pretty

`pino.info('Error doing that', Error)` <- prints {} for Error

`pino.info(Error, 'Error doing that')` <- prints the error in full

All my other logging, uses the more natural `message,data` format

Is there a way to switch the way pino processes the params to allow for objects/errors in the second param?

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by @jsumners in Fastify discord

https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=logmethod

```
const hooks = {
  logMethod (inputArgs, method, level) {
    if (inputArgs.length >= 2) {
      const arg1 = inputArgs.shift()
      const arg2 = inputArgs.shift()
      return method.apply(this, [arg2, arg1, ...inputArgs])
    }
    return method.apply(this, inputArgs)
  }
}
```